# Questions about the dot products of a unit cube

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, vector-spaces, inner-products, geometric-construction

1. I want to find the dot products(It should have 16 dot products.) of a unit cube's diagonal lines.

P.S. unit cube is a cube where all the lengths of 12 edges of the cube are 1.

2. It should have 16 dot products, right?
3. Moreover,  what is the projection of a vector on a plane in $R^n$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the inner product of a unit cube"? It's volume?

Comment: Like the inner product of (1,2,3) and (2,3,4) is 1*2+2*3+3*4=20 and -20

Comment: Imagine the unit cube sitting in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the four lower vertices being at $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1,1,0),(0,1,0)$ and the four upper vertices at $(0,0,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,1),(0,1,1)$. Then, one diagonal connects $(0,0,0)$ with $(1,1,1)$, and another diagonal connects e.g. $(0,1,0)$ with $(1,0,1)$. The two corresponding diagonal vectors are $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,-1,1)$, and so their inner product is $1$. However, the value of this product depends on the choice of diagonal points one connects, so it can be either $0$ or $\pm 1$.

Comment: Where does the $0$ come from? Do you mean when all four vertices live on the same face?

Comment: I have the same question. I also think the answers are 1 or -1. I still can't understand where does the 0 come form.

Comment: Yes, $0$ occurs when the two diagonals are chosen on the same face. If one only takes into account spacial diagonals, the only answers are $\pm 1$.

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray Additionlly, why you are not using the vectors like (1/2, 1/2, 1/2), (1/2, -1/2, 1/2)..., etc. I think using (1,1,1) is wrong, because we are not computing cosx here (where x is the angle of the diagonal lines). If we are computing the cosx, then they don't involve the distances of vectors, but here we are computing the dot product, so it involves the distances of vectors

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray  Sorry, if what I said above is wrong, then please correct my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second point: First, pick an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and choose an orthonormal basis $(e_1,e_2)$ of your plane $P\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. $e_1,e_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are two vectors with $\|e_1\|=\|e_2\|=1$ and $\langle e_1,e_2\rangle=0$.

Then, given any vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, its projection $\hat v$ to $P$ is given by
$$\hat v = \langle v,e_1\rangle e_1 + \langle v, e_2\rangle e_2.$$

In the special case of $n=3$, there also exists a special vector $e_3\in\mathbb{R}^3$ called the *unit normal vector* to $P$, which satisfies $\|e_3\|=1$ and $\langle e_1,e_3\rangle = \langle e_2,e_3\rangle = 0$. Using this vector, the projection of $v$ to $P$ can also be calculated as
$$\hat v = v - \langle v,e_3\rangle e_3.$$

Comment: More or less, have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix

Comment: What you said about projection are all correct, and I understood your answer. Thank you very much.